# ANTLR4 what does ATN stand for?

Tags: antlr, lexer

I'm surprised this is not explained anywhere on the ANTLR website nor in any of the documentation, but what does ATN (not ANT) stand for? Knowing what the acronym stands for would help me understand the role of the [`ATN`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATN.html), [`ATNSimulator`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNSimulator.html), etc. components of the library. Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: http://www.antlr.org/ -  ANother Tool for Language Recognition

Comment: not `ANT` but [`ATN`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATN.html) @RomanHocke

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @RomanHocke it's understandable, though. very confusing name. I wonder if it was a typo?

Comment: augmented transition network

Comment: @CoronA That seems very appropriate. post an answer and I will mark it correct if you can cite a source

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Augmented Transition Networks, the description in the context of ANTLR could be found e.g. here

http://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf